# Splashscreen not hidden using Cordova 3.5 on a remote page

Tags: html, cordova

Since 2.7.0, I was using Cordova to launch a remote page as an application, it worked.

I'm using the SplashScreen plugin.

With the 3.5.0, i cannot do same, in fact, when I launch a sample local page, no problems, `Cordova.js` handles the situation, and `navigator.splashscreen.hide()`, shutdown my splashscreen when page is loaded.

Now when I launch a remote website with the same html page including the cordova.js copied locally and referenced in my html, it goes wrong, when page is loaded, the splashscreen stays...

Why I can't use a remote website page including `Cordova.js` ?

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.sample" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Remote website</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="http://remote.website.com/index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <icon src="res/icon.png"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
</widget>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `cordova.js` interfaces with native code and therefore cannot load from a remote source. I am not sure how this was working for you in previous versions, but suspect it has to do with the structural changes made in the 3.X versioning of Cordova.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon So there is nothing that we can do, to load a remote website, and use the splashscreen plugin thought a remote `cordova.js`?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Cordova is designed to run locally on devices and in pair with native code. Remote site loading is discouraged as it opens a lot of issues in regards to how uses expect mobile apps to perform. Instead of remote loading, I use local files and make calls to remote services if I need external data or storage.